# Facing error while executing the command in PowerShell 2.0 while working fine in PowerShell 3 adn above

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am executing following code but facing error in PowerShell 2.0 while code works fine in latest version, please help is there any Snapin to solve this or any other solution except updating the PowerShell. Thanks in advance.

```
Code:  
  Write-Output $a |Tee-Object -FilePath $fileName 
  Write-Output("Please wait components deletion is in progress")|Tee-Object -FilePath $fileName -Append 

Error:
    Tee-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Append'.
    At line:1 char:102
  + Write-Output("Please wait components deletion is in progress")|Tee- Object -FilePath $fileName -Append
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Tee-Object], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TeeObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Tee-object has no `-Append` in PS 2.0. Even, MSDN page mentions this cmdlet as of PS 3.0: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937(v=wps.640).aspx

Comment: Then what would be the solution to run it on PowerShell 2.o ?

Comment: Change the code so that append will not be necessary, or use other cmdlet